# LEFT JOIN with WHERE and AND parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, database, request

I have the following tables :

**Movies :**

```
+----------+--------------+
| movie_id |     title    |
+----------+--------------+
|    1     | Wonder Woman |
+----------+--------------+
```

**Cast :**

```
+----------+--------------+
| id       |     name     |
+----------+--------------+
|    1     |   Gal Gadot  |
+----------+--------------+
|    2     |  Chris Pine  |
+----------+--------------+
```

**Movie_cast :**

```
+----------+--------------+--------------+
| id       |   movie_id   |    cast_id   |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
|    1     |       1      |       1      |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
|    2     |       1      |       2      |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
```

Basicly, Gal Gadot and Chris Pine are both part of the movie Wonder Woman.

My problem is that I want to find all of the movies in which they are **both** in. I don't want any movie in which they play separately, only where they are both are in the cast.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM movies
LEFT JOIN movie_cast ON movie_cast.movie_id = movies.movie_id 
LEFT JOIN cast ON movie_cast.cast_id = cast.id
WHERE cast.id = 1 AND cast.id = 2
```

But the result was empty.

Comment: of course result will be empty because you add and logical operator in where condition and as a result no rows will match your result so only replace and operator with or operator and you will get results

Comment: Cast.id cannot be 1 and 2 at the same time. Hence no rows returned.

Comment: @WaelJazmaty using OR wouldn't do it since i don't want all the movie in which they played but only the moovie in which they played TOGETHER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
SELECT m.movie_id, m.title 
FROM movies m
INNER JOIN movie_cast mc ON mc.movie_id = m.movie_id 
WHERE mc.cast_id = 1 OR mc.cast_id = 2
GROUP BY m.movie_id, m.title
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2; -- HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT mc.cast_id) = 2; -- for unnormalized data
```

No need LEFT JOIN, and you only need to JOIN `cast`table when you need to find by cast's name

Comment: Almost there but i'm still getting result of movie in which they don't play together somehow.

I'v tried it with 2 other actors and i have the same result, there is always some movies in which they are not playing together (checked in the database)

Comment: @Ethrak If you could check it, then with error case get the movie_id (e.g: n) and plz run this and check how many rows you get: SELECT * FROM movies m
INNER JOIN movie_cast mc ON mc.movie_id = m.movie_id 
WHERE (mc.cast_id = 1 OR mc.cast_id = 2) AND m.movie_id = n;

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery in the FROM clause to narrow down the movies where they are both in. By limiting the cast to only their ID numbers and GROUPing it, any movie_id that has a Cast_Total of 2 will have both of those individuals starring in it.

```
SELECT m.title
FROM (SELECT movie_id, COUNT(cast_id) AS Cast_Total
      FROM movie_cast 
      WHERE cast_id IN (1, 2)
      GROUP BY movie_id) temp
LEFT JOIN movies m ON m.movie_id = temp.movie_id
WHERE temp.Cast_Total = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

SELF JOIN Movie_cast to get movies with two actors then join it to movies.

```
SELECT * FROM Movies A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT M1.movie_id movie_id FROM Movie_cast 
M1 INNER JOIN Movie_cast M2 ON M1.movie_id = M2.movie_id
WHERE M1.cast_id = 1 AND M2.cast_id = 2) B
ON A.movie_id = B.movie_id
```

Generic version, get Movies that have missing cast (Say table A). Left join main movies with this set A and filter out movies having missing cast.

```
SELECT * FROM Movies A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT DISTINCT movie_id movie_id 
FROM Movie_cast M1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Cast WHERE Id = M1.cast_id) 
) B ON A.Id = B.movie_id
WHERE B.movie_id IS NULL
```